# iframe content causes the text on my page to go blurry

Tags: html, css, iframe, blurry

I have an iframe container on my page that loads a map when i click on a button. And for some reason, when the map loads it causes surrounding objects to go blurry.

**Example:** https://i.postimg.cc/xCfJWwZG/beforeafter.png

I have tried adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` to various things in the CSS and `transform: scale(1.0) translate3d(0,0,0);` which only makes the objects permanently blurry. How do i stop the iframe from screwing up my page.

Comment: did you try to wrap it in a container and set its `position` to `relative`?

Comment: Added it as an answer so that people with similar problem will find it. Please accept it Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding it as an answer so that people looking for similar problem will find it.

Sometimes the content of the `iframe` has absolutely positioned elements inside that due to css positioning might take up the whole screen if the `iframe` is not positioned `relative` to some container.

So it seems in this case this is the problem.

So try to wrap the `iframe` in a container and set its `position:relative` to fix it.

Comment: sorry but the problem seems to have come back with a vengeance. It now makes everything on my page blurry again and putting it in a div with `position:relative` isn't helping 

Comment: Please provide a live link or a way to reproduce the issue so I can take a look and try to see what is the problem..

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is not being directly caused by the position:absolute css property but is caused by anti-aliasing due subpixel positioning of the iframe.

With either positioning using a % value or using a transform with % values the iframe can be inadvertently positioned in a subpixel position i.e. left is set to 10% and that calculates to say 10.5px. That results in the iframe content appearing blurred.

In my case something as simple as an odd value (35px) for padding on a ancestor element resulting in an odd value for width and then a left:10% on the iframe was enough to cause the problem, setting the padding to an even number then removed the problem.