# Focus on input inside IFrame making content blur

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, widget

I have created an iframe which opens a chat site that i built using React.js and Tailwind. The iframe on the website is being loaded dynamically using javascript. When i am clicking on input inside the iframe , the whole content inside iframe is becoming blurry. On normal view it is looking fine but when i zoom and check, the content clearly becomes blurry and as soon as I remove the focus from input it is back to normal. The same is not happening with the react application.

I have attached the relevant screenshots, let me know if something else is also required.

[image: Text became blurry when focus on input]

[image: Text is normal when focus is not on input]

Here are the necessary links to test -
[Widget Site](https://chat-widget-plum.vercel.app/)
[Chat Application](https://brainstormer-chat.vercel.app/)

Edit - [GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/k6h1v7EuWmloupCyE8)

Comment: I don't see it in the app link you've provided. Could you try and create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? One thing I'd recommend is try this on different device, see if it happens.

Comment: I can see this happening on my mobile device as well. Can you try again, i have removed the check for the loading of widget. https://chat-widget-plum.vercel.app/

Comment: Still don't see it. Even at 420% zoom. It can be your device hardware or browser specific settings for hardware acceleration.

Comment: I am using samsung galaxy book. When i zoom in using trackpad by pinching, it doesnt changes the zoom of the browser if that makes sense. I have attached the gif. You can also replicate the same issue in mobile browser.

Comment: From your description, I'm assuming that's a zoom on your OS level. Regardless, could you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616390/iframe-content-causes-the-text-on-my-page-to-go-blurry)? See if it helps.

Comment: yep, tried this as well, didn't worked

Answer (score -1):

Try any of this

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: red;//any color you want
}

/* Firefox < 19 */

input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: red;//any color you want
}

/* Firefox > 19 */

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
   color: red;//any color you want
}

/* Internet Explorer 10 */

input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: red;//any color you want
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem.